# Unable to start kafka using docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

I want to start kafka using docker command but zookeeper is showing some error.
**
error-**

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:344)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1290)
```

I use this commands

```
docker run -p 2181:2181 zookeeper
```

Start Kafka Container, expose PORT 9092 and setup ENV variables.

```
docker run -p 9092:9092 \
-e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=<PRIVATE_IP>:2181 \
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<PRIVATE_IP>:9092 \
-e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
   confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

also it is showing error if I use the docker_config.yaml file-

file

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    restart: always
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
    networks:
      - kafka_elk_network

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    networks:
      - kafka_elk_network
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  kafka_manager:
    image: hlebalbau/kafka-manager:stable
    container_name: kafka-manager
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: "zookeeper:2181"  # Change this line
      APPLICATION_SECRET: "random-secret"
    command: -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    networks:
      - kafka_elk_network

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.15.0
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
    networks:
      - kafka_elk_network

networks:
  kafka_elk_network:
    driver: bridge
```

error-

```
2023-08-30 19:10:05,337 - [WARN] o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server zookeeper:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
kafka-manager    | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address zookeeper:2181 because it's not resolvable
kafka-manager    |  at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:66)
kafka-manager    |  at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:39)
kafka-manager    |  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1087)
kafka-manager    |  at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1139)
kafka-manager    | 2023-08-30 19:10:06,438 - [ERROR] o.a.z.c.StaticHostProvider - Unable to resolve address: zookeeper:2181
kafka-manager    | java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper
```

I want anyone to suggest what I should do,to fix this issue and I want to run this on local machine

Comment: Do not use both `docker run` and `docker compose` together. Pick one. Seems you are getting an error somewhere because Zookeeper container did not start (probably since port 2181 is already taken)... 1) What is `<PRIVATE_IP>` 2) Kafka doesn't need Zookeeper anymore - https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/kafka/docker-compose.yml 3) Did you mean to change `image: wurstmeister/kafka` to use a different image?